# Swift 2.0: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context (Using Parse)

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary, parse-platform, swift2

I keep receiving the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context".  My code is as follows:

```
func fetchUnviewedUsers(callback: ([User]) -> ()) {

PFQuery(className: "Action").whereKey("byUser", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!).findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

   let seenIDS = map(objects, {$0.objectForKey("toUser")!})
    PFUser.query()!
        .whereKey("objectId", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        .whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: seenIDS)
        .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
            objects, error in
            if let pfUsers = objects as? [PFUser] {
                let users = pfUsers.map({pfUserToUser($0)})
                callback(users)
            }
            }
    )
}
}
```

The error is in this line:

```
   let seenIDS = map(objects, {$0.objectForKey("toUser")!})
```

specifically at the "$0".

Additionally, I am pretty sure that in Swift 2.0 you can't use the 'map' function in the way that it is in the code above.  This code isn't mine, but I've been working on converting it from Swift 1.2 to 2.0, and this is the final issue that I am having.

Hopefully somebody much more knowledgable than me can help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let seenIDS = objects?.map { ($0 as? NSDictionary)?.objectForKey("toUser") as! String } ?? []
```

Comment: Tried it and got more errors:

"_Cast from '[AnyObject]' to unrelated type 'PFObject' always fails_" and "_'map' is unavailable: call the 'map()' method on the optional value_" on the same line as the last error.

And "_Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject??' to expected argument type '[AnyObject]'_" on the line `.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: seenIDS)`

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this by the way.  Very much appreciated

Comment: I edited my answer above but I made an assumption that you are expecting an array of strings (`toUser` values being of type String). If there is nothing, you should get an empty string.

Comment: Worked for me!  THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THE HELP